# How to I retrieve a user selection from ComboBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have the following ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="splitInput_ComboBox" SelectionChanged="spltComboBox_SelectionChanged"> 
       <ComboBoxItem Tag="0" IsSelected="True">None</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem  Tag="2">2</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem Tag="3">3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

How can I assign the user selection to an int or double variable in the code behind? Is data binding the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: for ex, when the user selects 2 you want it to store in a int with value 2 ?

Comment: Yes. I may be new to the XAML/C# realm, but this seems like it should be super simple, yet I cannot seem to find any solutions! It's driving me mad.

Comment: you can get the SelectedIndex (int) or SelectedItem (convert to Int) , is it not what you want ?

Comment: You know, the latter was, and I literally just figured it out from a .NET 4.5 tutorial of all places. For some reason when I tried that the first time it just did not work, but it worked this time. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your spltComboBox_SelectionChanged event handler you can get selected item or selected value using these properties:

> SelectedItem
>
> SelectedValue

like:

```
splitInput_ComboBox.SelectedValue;
```

**Note:** I recommend you not to use underscore while naming your controls as you did *"splitInput_ComboBox"*.